# Is it possible to sum a value if the substraction of two value on the same row equals something?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I'm trying to build a sheet where I can see how much I have to pay each month.

Let's say I have the following table

| Current installment (CI) | Total installments (TI) | Installment amount (IA) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | $100 |
| 1 | 1 | $200 |
| 2 | 3 | $150 |
| 1 | 3 | $75 |
| 2 | 4 | $150 |
| 1 | 1 | $50 |

So, the first month would be if TI-CI >= 1, then I will sum that value. For the following month I would do the same but TI-CI >= 2

And the result would be something like this

| - | - |
| --- | --- |
| 1st month debt | $475 (the result of 100+150+75+100) |
| 2nd month debt | $325 (the result of 100+75+150) |
| 3rd month debt | $100 |

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IFNA(SUM(FILTER(C$2:C, (B$2:B-A$2:A)>=ROW(A1))))
```

and drag down

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer